# Leer autómata desde archivo de texto

Tags: python

Tengo como objetivo poder simular un autómata obteniendo la información desde un archivo de texto con la siguiente estructura:

- S = {a,b,c}
- Q = {q0,q1,q2,q3}
- F = {q0,q3}
- D = {(q0,a,{q1,q2}),(q1,b,q2),(q2,c,q3)}
- q0 = q0

Para S, Q, F y q0 ya he podido obtener los datos, pero D, al ser un poco más complejo, no he logrado obtener cada estado y transición. Mi idea es ponerlos en una lista de la siguiente forma:
[ [qo, a, [q1,q2] ] , [q1, b, q2] , [q2, c, q3] ]
La lectura de los otros datos la hago de la siguiente forma:

```
        text = f.readline()
        S = text[text.find('{')+1:text.find('}')]
        S = S.split(',')
```

Comment: Podrías agregar un ejemplo del contenido del txt por favor? Y pregunta. Se permiten usar expresiones regulares?

Comment: @DanteS. El contenido del txt es el que coloqué en la pregunta. S, Q, F, D y q0 corresponden a cada linea del txt.

Comment: y si se permiten expresiones regulares??

Comment: Sí, se permiten expresiones regulares.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Planteando solución

Si nos ponemos a analizar cuidadosamente la entrada y la salida que deseamos entonces podemos observar que para llegar de `{(q0,a,{q1,q2}),(q1,b,q2),(q2,c,q3)}` a `[[qo, a, [q1,q2] ] , [q1, b, q2] , [q2, c, q3] ]`  vemos que lo único que ha cambiado son 3 cosas:

1. Los caracteres `{` y `}`  han  sido cambiados por `[` y `]`
2. Los caracteres `(` y `)` han sido cambiados por `[` y `]`
3. Claramente ya no tenemos un string sino una lista.

## Posible primera solución

Centrándonos en los 2 primeros puntos, podemos usar el método `replace` de los strings para cambiar caracteres, por lo que podemos hacer:

```py
D = "{(q0,a,{q1,q2}),(q1,b,q2),(q2,c,q3)}"

D = D.replace("{","[").replace("}","]").replace("(","[").replace(")","]")
```

Y obtendríamos un string con sintaxis de lista y dado que tiene sintaxis de lista podemos usar la función `eval()` que evalúa un string como código python ejecutable, pero su uso es bastante peligroso.

Sin ebargo...... si hacemos `eval(D)` esto no dará un error diciendo que hay variables no definidas, esto porqué `q0`,`q1`,`q2`, etc son tomadas como variables debido a que no están entre comillas (`""` ó `''`). Por tal motivo **todo el procedimiento anterior queda descartado**, pero la lógica nop.

## Solución

Tomando la lógica anterior de reemplazar los `{}` y `()`por `[]`, simplemente nos queda reemplazar los datos `q0`,`q1`,`q2`, etc. por `'q0'`,`'q1'`,etc. y para eso utilizaré expresiones regulares y el módulo `re`.

```py
import re

D = "{(q0,a,{q1,q2}),(q1,b,q2),(q2,c,q3)}"

#generando expresión regular para detectar letras
regex = re.compile("\w+")

#buscamos las coincidencias y reemplazamos
for i in set(regex.findall(D)):
    D=D.replace(i, f"'{i}'")

#reemplazamos llaves y parentesis por corchetes
D = re.sub("{|\(", "[", D)
D = re.sub("}|\)", "]", D)

D = eval(D)
print(D)
```

El truco está en el ciclo `for`, pues obtenemos todas las partes literales del string y eso lo convertimos a un `set` para evitar datos repetidos y entonces iteramos en ese `set` y reemplazamos cada coincidencia de por la esa misma palabra pero añadido comillas simples (`'`) antes y después de la coincidencia. Luego `re.sub()` nos ayuda a reemplazar los caracteres, es lo mismo que toda la sentencia anterior `D.replace("{","[").replace("}","]")...` pero en este caso aproveché el modulo `re` para acortar más las cosas.

## Detalles

- Construir una expresión regular (proceso que se hace por detrás) es algo bastante costoso y eso hace que mi solución no sea la más eficiente, pero claro, recordemos que con cosas pequeñas la diferencia es imperceptible, mientras no tengas una cadena mayor a 100 000 caracteres de longitud no hay problema y todo trabajará bien
- También puedes usar el módulo `ast` y su método `literal_eval` que evalúa de una forma más segura la expresión que se le pase. La diferencia con `eval()` es que este ejecuta sea lo que sea que se le pase, si se le pasa `del variable` se borrará la variable, pero `literal_eval()` solo acepta cadenas literales de diccionarios, tuplas, string, números, set, booleanos y `None` y yo aconsejo su uso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He comprendido la lógica y cual es el camino que se toma, pero al llegar a evaluar el resultado da un error de sintaxis.
[['q0','a',[''q1'','''q2''']],[''q1'','b','''q2'''],['''q2''','c','q3']]
Esto debido que se se colocaron dos comillas simples juntas.
Me has dado la casi la solución. Intentaré arreglar eso y, espero, logre terminar.

Comment: Perdón, que me he olvidado de convertir `re.findall()` en un `set` con `set(re.findall(D))`. Lo he explicado en la respuesta pero no la había añadido >_<, ahora lo corrijo y con eso ya funciona :D

Comment: @13p14 ya lo he corregido, avísame cualquier cosa

Comment: ¡Funciona! Ya no duplica las comillas simples cada vez que encuentra el mismo estado. Muchas gracias n.n